# shortest expression to return false for negative number and the number itself for positive number (or zero)

Tags: javascript

What is the shortest expression I can use to return `false` for all `numbers < 0` and the number itself for all `numbers >= 0`?

Left is what I have, right is want I want to be returned.

```
-3: false
-1: false
 0:  0
 1:  1
23: 23
```

Something really short like:

```
(!!number)   <-- (doenst work)
```

Comment: return number < 0 ? false : number;

Comment: Probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @j08691 code review is for reviewing working code; there is no working code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something shorter, you could do:

```
return number >= 0 && number;
```

If `number >= 0` is `false`, then `&&` will evaluate to the left operand (i.e. `false`). Otheriwse, it evaluates to the right operand (i.e. the number).

Answer (score 2):

without any checking whether number is actually a number:

```
return number < 0 ? false : number;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return number < 0 ? false : number;
```

Answer (score 0):

**A very short one:**

```
0>number?!1:number
```

Minified: `0>n?!1:n`

Hint: `!1 === false`

---

**Demo:**

```js
var numbers = [
  -5, // > false
  0,  // > 0
  5   // > 5
];

numbers.forEach(function(n) {
  console.log(
    0>n?!1:n
  );
});
```